# How do I show the tabcontent, after clicked on one of the menu tabs (both dont work) in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a JSFiddle for this:

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/xrtk9enc/2/>
```

I think the problem must be in the javascript part. I have in my html code an Unordered List, which is the tab menu. 
My href of the menu goes to the tab content, which I want to have that if the div is .tabactive class it is being shown (display : block) and that the other 3 divs are 'display : none' in the CSS.
I've been stuck here for a week I dont get it how I need to
 do it.

Anyone here who can help me with this problem?

Edit:

Sorry but I do NOT want to use jQuery.

Comment: Also sorry for the weird link to jsfiddle, it said that it needs to be accompanied by code. Idk what that means.

Comment: What is tabClick it is not defined anywhere?  If you want to use tabs i suggest using JQuery tabs.  It will reduce your code significantly and give you less headaches. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

Something with the help of Jquery

```js
$("ul.tab-links li").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    var tab = $(this).data('tab');
    $("ul.tab-links").find('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(".tab-content").find('[id^=tab]').removeClass("tabactive").addClass('tab');
    $(".tab-content").find('#tab' + tab).removeClass("tab").addClass("tabactive");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: blue;    
}

.tabs {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
    /*----- Tab Links -----*/
    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content:'';
    }
 
    .tab-links li {
        margin:0px 5px;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }
 
        .tab-links a {
            padding:9px 15px;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
            background:#7FB5DA;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:600;
            color:#4c4c4c;
            transition:all linear 0.15s;
        }
 
        .tab-links a:hover {
            background:#a7cce5;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
 
    li.active a, li.active a:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#4c4c4c;
    }
 
    /*----- Content of Tabs -----*/
    .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
    }
 
        .tab {
            display:none;
        }
 
        .tabactive{
            display:block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type="text/css"/>
 <script src='script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
   <li class="active" data-tab="1"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
    <li data-tab="2"><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    <li data-tab="3"><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
    <li data-tab="4"><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
</ul>
 
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabactive">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>lol</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>lol</p>
        </div>
 
        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>lol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after looking at your code, your problem is threefold.

1. jsfiddle doesn't like it when you use onclick attribute. I have no idea why, but I couldn't get it to  work no matter how hard I tried. That's just a problem with jsfiddle though, your code worked much better when I turned it into a html doc.
2. For some reason the `removeAttribute('class', 'tabactive');` method returned undefined and broke the rest of the code. Not sure why you would want to remove the element in this case, shouldn't you just change it to the tab class like all of the rest of the hidden tabs?
3. You set a second parameter in the tabclick function. This wasn't actually set when you called the function on the onclick attribute. I made it so that that parameter returns the id of what tab div you want to show.

The new tabClick function:

`function tabClick(tab, tabContent) {
    var newcontent=document.getElementById(tabContent);
    document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].removeAttribute('class', 'active');
    tab.setAttribute('class', 'active');
    document.getElementsByClassName('tabactive')[0].setAttribute('class', 'tab');
    newcontent.setAttribute('class', 'tabactive');
}`

The new HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
   <li class="active" onclick="javascript:tabClick(this,'tab1')"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
    <li onclick="javascript:tabClick(this,'tab2')"><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    <li onclick="javascript:tabClick(this,'tab3')"><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
    <li onclick="javascript:tabClick(this,'tab4')" ><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tabactive">
        <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
        <p>lol</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
        <p>lol</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab4" class="tab">
        <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
        <p>lol</p>
    </div>
</div>
```